# How to make Red 5 media server stream different formats of files?

Tags: streaming, red5, transcoding

I need to stream both audio and video files from the Red 5 server. By default Red 5 only supports flash, but I need to add support for other file types too.

I need to dynamically (on the run time) transcode the media file in one format to desired formats  as per client request. Is it possible ? How to go for it ? I have been reading of vlcj project, but dont know how to integrate them.

If audio / video transcoding is not possible in Red 5, is there any other open source alternative I can look forward to ?

Any help will be really appreciated...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `StreamableFileFactory` bean inside your `red5-common.xml`, to see what kind of files can be streamed by default (flv, mp3, mp4, m4a). If you copy any of these files in your red5 service's streaming directory, it will be able to play it.

If the source you need to stream is in different format (like youtube uploads), then the best way for you to go is [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

1. You build it to your server, then
2. from inside your red5
   service check whether there are any
   unsupported files in your streaming
   directory (should be a scheduled job), and
3. if so, use ffmpeg with the proper
   parameters to convert the new files
   to streamable formats.

that's it.

Comment: Can you please give some time to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846816/can-we-stream-only-flash-videos-throught-rtmp. Thanks !