# Can we stream only flash videos throught RTMP?

Tags: streaming, red5, rtmp

I am planning to use Red5 streaming server. The documentation says it uses only RTMP - I am confused if I can stream media in formats other than flash.

Is it possible to stream MP4 / RM / AVI files through RTMP - or rather Red5 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [red5 google site](http://code.google.com/p/red5/), from there you can learn, that Red5

- is able to stream not only over RTMP
  but also RTMPT, RTMPS, and RTMPE
  protocols, and
- can stream not only FLV but also F4V,
  MP4, 3GP, MP3, F4A, M4A and AAC media
  formats.

For RM and AVI you must use a converter to create the appropriate streamable formats. The best way in my opinion to do so is using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).
If you need to convert media on the fly, you can use ffmpeg from your java classes. It's easy and offers a large list of parameters 'guaranteeing' that you'll get what you need.

Comment: Thanks rekaszeru ! I am planning to use Xuggler for transcoding. I just wonder why Red5 is called an "Open Source Flash Server" when it can support so many formats... My issue is to stream some media files to iPhone, where flash is not supported. I still wonder if Red5 is of some help !!